# confirm use of jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
    var xhr = _orgAjax();
    DoSomeLogging();
    return xhr;
};
```

I've inherited the code above. Can someone confirm my understanding that this will override any `$.ajax(...)` call anywhere else on the page and execute `DoSomeLogging()` each time?

I'm hunting a different bug but stumbled upon this and wanted to be sure I understand what this piece of legacy code does?

I'm not convinced this is good practice/use of the `xhr` function anyway but interested to hear your opinions. We're using Jquery 1.7.1.

Lastly, out of curiosity, what if `_orgAjax()` failed to return if an (`async: false`) call, would the logging method even get reached?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to test this by yourself (or is it *for* yourself - not sure)? Create a new page, insert the above code, make some `$.ajax()` requests. Is `DoSomeLogging` invoked?

Comment: How can `_origAjax` fail to return? You mean, if an error is thrown within it? In that case, obviously, the entire JavaScript program would terminate (stop executing).

Comment: The request is not made at this point so it doesn't matter if it's synchronous or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone confirm my understanding that this will override any
>   $.ajax(...) call anywhere else on the page and execute DoSomeLogging()
>   each time?

Yes. This will define the global default behaviour unless overwritten in a local ajax implementation.

The more documented way of defining global settings is the use of [**ajaxSetup()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

However, you are able to set default global behaviour using `ajaxSettings` as well, though this particular way is not documented anywhere directly in the jQuery documentation.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/Sffuf/) - With Success

> Lastly, out of curiosity, what if _orgAjax() failed to return if an
>   (async: false) call, would the logging method even get reached?

The settings are configuring the `beforeSend` so the logging method will always be called regardless of the async setting as pointed out correctly by **Esailija**.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/d3PzG/1/) - with `async: true`, logging is called before return
See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/d3PzG/) - with `async: false`, logging is also called before return

However please note though, according to the [**ajax documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> *As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is*
>   *deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.*

I know you are using 1.7.1 but if something becomes deprecated there usually is a good reason and I don't see any harm in preparing for that.

To configure ajax with logging on `complete` by default:

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/aTpmX/) - Configuring default logging for `complete` for document.
I know that would make your logging being executed after and not before the send but that seems to be the way 1.8 prefers it I think.

Comment: The `async` option does not affect how `_orgAjax()` behaves, it's simply a factory function for XMLHttpRequest objects.

Comment: @Esailija: Never mind I now got your point, reading your other comment, I will re-phrase. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Esailija: I re=phrased and added some demos with async set to false and true to show that either-way logging is called before the request is send. I suppose, going by the 1.8 notes, if one has to use `complete` when setting async: false with a deferred callback in the future, logging would always be called after or not at all if the call doesn't return.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you could:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function () {
        doSomeLogging();   
    }
});
```

That's certainly simpler than having to redefine `$.ajaxSettings.xhr`.